# Use a generic type as associated type, without phantom data

Tags: rust

I have a trait defining an associated type:

```rust
pub trait View: Default {
    type State;
    fn draw(&mut self, state: &mut Self::State);
}
```

I have a type suitable for the `State` associated type, but it's generic:

```rust
pub struct MenuState<I> {
    pub items: Vec<I>,
}
```

The following code can't compile (rust 1.66) because `I` isn't constrained:

```rust
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct MenuView {
    // fields here
}
impl<I: ToString + Copy> View for MenuView {
    type State = MenuState<I>;
    fn draw(&mut self, _state: &mut Self::State) { }
}
```

(note: the `ToString` and `Copy` constraints are needed for the implementation of `MenuView`)

I know how to solve that by adding some phantom data to make `MenuView` generic on `I` (see [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d6b5531a5edad90b0d186c7fe4d192fb)) but it's ugly and seems too much complicated. I feel like the code pasted above just needs some syntactic fix.

Is there a simple solution, without changing the `View` trait and not involving a phantom ?

If a syntactic fix can't be defined for some fundamental reason, what is that reason ?

Comment: (Your playground link is broken.) What will `I` equal to? There is a single implementation of `View` for `MenuView`, but there are multiple possible `I`s.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Sorry, fixed the playground link. `MenuView` and `MenuState` should compile for any `I` implementing `ToString` and `Copy`.

Comment: Side note: prefer `PhantomData<fn() -> T>` to `PhantomData<T>`, because then it always implements auto-traits and not only if `T` implements them.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thanks. That's indeed a side note but it's useful to me, I didn't think about that.

Comment: As @Stargateur made me realize in the chat, this is mostly an XY question.
The `View` type shouldn't have been defined with an associated type as it could just be generic on the `State` type. I'll let him answer. So the "fundamental" reason `MenuView` needs a type is that the use case of the associated type isn't just generic arguments given to a trait's function.

Comment: This not syntactically allowed because traits are conceptually functions from traits to behavior. Importantly, that means a *single-valued* function. Your "generic impl", if it were allowed, would mean that `MenuView` implemented `View` many times, once for each `I`. But you're only allowed to implement a trait once. All this in short form: what do you think `<MenuView as View>::State` should be?

Comment: Some addendum, but it's going to be off-topic. The associated type pattern here has still benefits. Making `MenuView` not generic means that users of this type has more type annotation to add. For example with Menu defined as `pub struct Menu<I> { state: MenuState<I>, view: MenuView }`, the implementation of `Menu` must specify which `MenuView` is used. It can't just do `self.view.some_fn();` in a self function but must do `<MenuView as View<MenuState<I>>>::some_fn(&mut self.view);`. Of course, when using an associated type, the complexity is moved to defining the phantomData in `MenuView`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without changing the `View` trait, `PhantomData` is the correct solution, your generic must appear somewhere either in the trait or in the struct. `State` is something that is "associate" to `MenuView` and so there is no other way than to include it.

However, your case could suggest `View` is not well defined to your usage, maybe a generic would be more appropriate than an associate type. Like:

```rust
pub trait View<State>: Default {
    fn draw(&mut self, state: &mut State);
}

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct MenuState<I> {
    pub items: Vec<I>,
}

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct MenuView {}

impl<I: ToString + Copy + Default> View<MenuState<I>> for MenuView {
    fn draw(&mut self, _state: &mut MenuState<I>) {}
}
```

This more or less transforms your original trait, from, implement `View` for `MenuView` that have a `State`, to, implement `View` a `State` for `MenuView`.